# Add row after the last element of a group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Concerning pandas, I have 2 dataframes:

Dataframe 1:
0 | a | 0
1 | a | 1
2 | a | 2
3 | b | 0
4 | b | 2
5 | c | 0
6 | c | 7
... (it continues)

Dataframe 2:
0 | a | x
1 | b | y
2 | c | z
... (it continues)

Dataframe1:
I need to add x,y after the last element of each group in dataframe1. The resulting dataframe shall look like this:

Resulting dataframe:
0 |  a | 0
1 |  a | 1
2 |  a | 2
3 |  a | x
4 |  b | 0
5 |  b | 2
6 |  b | y
...

Any ideas? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If values in `df1` are sorted by first column, then use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) + [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) + [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2]).sort_values('a').reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
    a   b
0   a   0
1   a   1
2   a   2
3   a   x
4   b   0
5   b   2
6   b   y
7   c   0
8   c   7
9   c   z
```

For sorting values in `df1` use:

```
df1 = df1.sort_values('a')
```

Input:

```
print (df1)
   a  b
0  a  0
1  a  1
2  a  2
3  b  0
4  b  2
5  c  0
6  c  7

print (df2)
    a   b
0   a   0
1   a   1
2   a   2
3   a   x
4   b   0
5   b   2
6   b   y
7   c   0
8   c   7
9   c   z
10  c  z1
```

Another solution by comment of [Corley Brigman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46688469/add-row-after-the-last-element-of-a-group/46688590?noredirect=1#comment80325139_46688590):

```
df = pd.concat([df1.set_index('a'),df2.set_index('a')]).sort_index().reset_index()
print (df)
    a   b
0   a   0
1   a   1
2   a   2
3   a   x
4   b   0
5   b   2
6   b   y
7   c   0
8   c   7
9   c   z
10  c  z1
```

Comment: if column b is filled with dates (e.g. 2014-09-01 08:51:00) is it possible to do the same? Sorry, I'm new with Pandas

Comment: Yes, sure. All sorting is by first `a` column.

Comment: if column b is dates, you may want column b to be your index in both.... `df.set_index('b')`... and if the indexes are unique, you can just do append or concat...

Comment: @MiloVentimiglia - If it does not work, can you change data with datetimes?

Comment: The dataframe 2 is a separate dataframe. When you concatenate, it adds the columns.  How do I join dataframe2 at the bottom of dataframe1?

Comment: Try second solution, but the best is same columns in both dataframes, else get NaNs.

Comment: Mate, it worked fine. Great idea. Simple and effective! Cheers!